# Identifying an app used in a touch pen promo

Tags: ipad, applications, apple

Anyone have any idea what app is used in the [lunatik touch pen promo](http://www.mnml.com/21277/341930/our-work/lunatik-touch-pen) materials?

This one:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Autodesk Sketchbook (which Michael suggests) does appear in the promo video in your link, the app in the photo is [Clibe](http://myclibe.com/) (see for instance: http://www.knowyourapps.com/reviews/clibe/ ).

I clipped out the UI from one of the Clibe screenshots for comparison. I have not used the app myself.

[image]

Comment: Interesting.. "Currently not available in the US store" Gotta love iTunes.

Comment: that's it.  too bad i cant get it here in the states.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple apps used in the video on that page, but at the 1:48 mark the app is [Autodesk Sketchbook Pro for iPad](http://www.autodesk.com/products/sketchbook-pro/features/all/gallery-view).

Comment: This tool icon was the giveaway http://postimg.org/image/4as1t5jsr/ please mark answer as correct if I'm right :)

Comment: Its not. The OP's linked page has a video at the bottom. At time 1:48 you'll see Sketchbook (which I sometimes use on android). The OP's image above is a different user interface and seems to have a journal paradigm (see the simulated pages at user's right-hand edge.)